# The given path's format is not supported c# Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#

string path = Path.Combine("~/Content/Images/"+pic.FileName);
pic.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));

Comment: Is there a question here?  Is the title an actual error you're getting?  Which line throws the error?  Which operation throws the error?  What is the runtime value of `pic.FileName`?  Of `path`?  The output of `Server.MapPath(path)`?  Please elaborate on what you're trying to ask.

Comment: string path = Path.Combine("~/Content/Images/"+pic.FileName); this line is throwing exception of invalid path format.... run time file name is pic. I'm trying to upload an image to "~/Content/Images" folder in solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/");
pic.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, pic.FileName));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot....@BoredomOverload . Exception has gone but the file is not uploading to folder....

Comment: @Adnan that's too bad, but i think that's a question of its own and isn't connected to this issue. Hope you work it out! :)